# Pandas Dataframe: "ValueError: could not convert string to float" when trying to change value of second column entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a short code where I want to be able to change values of a csv.
My Code is the following:

```
import pandas as 
import os

if os.path.exists('annotation.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv('annotation.csv')

label = 'unknown'
img_number = 99

if str(df.at[img_number, 'label_2']) == 'nan':
    df.at[img_number, 'label_2'] = label

else:
    continue
```

My file looks like this:

```
label_1,label_2
,
,
, 
,
,
(and so on)
```

I am able to change `'label_1'` in `df.at[img_number, 'label_2']`
but if I try replace it `'label_2'` I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "D:/develop/mbuchwald/machinelearning/Organ_Annotation/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    df.at[img_number, 'label_2'] = label
  File "C:\Users\mbuchwald\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\newEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2159, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Users\mbuchwald\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\newEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2582, in _set_value
    engine.set_value(series._values, index, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 124, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
  File "pandas/_libs/src\util.pxd", line 150, in util.set_value_at
  File "pandas/_libs/src\util.pxd", line 142, in util.set_value_at_unsafe
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'unknown'
```

Has anyone a clue. I can´t figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: your label2 column is of type float while label1 is of type object (str). You should probably leave numeric unknowns as `nan` as that is what `nan` is often used for. Otherwise you need convert `label2` to type object (`df['label_2'] =df['label_2'].astype(str)`)

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. But I it's a puzzle to me where this diferrent astype of the `label_1` and `label_2`column came from.
I simply created the csv with pd.Dataframe and df.to_csv.